# hibernate gives two rows the same instead of two distinct rows

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I have a user dao

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EBIGUSERTIM")
public class EbigUser {


private String id;
private Integer source;
private String entryscheme;
private String fullName;
private String email;

private Long flags;
private String status;
private String createdBy;
private Date createdStamp;
private String modifiedBy;
private Date modifiedStamp;

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Id
@Column(name="SOURCE")
public Integer getSource() {
    return source;
}
public void setSource(Integer source) {
    this.source = source;
}
@Column(name="ENTRYSCHEME")
public String getEntryscheme() {
    return entryscheme;
}
public void setEntryscheme(String entryscheme) {
    this.entryscheme = entryscheme;
}
@Column(name="FULLNAME")
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
@Column(name="EMAIL")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
@Column(name="FLAGS")
public Long getFlags() {
    return flags;
}
public void setFlags(Long flags) {
    this.flags = flags;
}
@Column(name="STATUS")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
@Column(name="CREATEDBY")
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}
public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}
@Column(name="CREATEDSTAMP")
public Date getCreatedStamp() {
    return createdStamp;
}
public void setCreatedStamp(Date createdStamp) {
    this.createdStamp = createdStamp;
}
@Column(name="MODIFIEDBY")
public String getModifiedBy() {
    return modifiedBy;
}
public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}
@Column(name="MODIFIEDSTAMP")
public Date getModifiedStamp() {
    return modifiedStamp;
}
public void setModifiedStamp(Date modifiedStamp) {
    this.modifiedStamp = modifiedStamp;
}
```

i am selecting 2 rows out of the db. The sql works

```
select * from ebigusertim where id='blah'
```

It returns 2 distinct rows. When i query the data using hibernate, it appears that the object memory is not being allocated for each entry in the list. Thus, i get 2 entries in the list with the same object.

```
        Criteria userCriteria = session.createCriteria(EbigUser.class);
        userCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        userlist = userCriteria.list();
```

Comment: Please pick a better title for your question, "problem" in titles is banned from Stack Overflow, and the only reason you managed to sneak it in is because you asked this on Programmers, the system would reject it automatically if you tried to ask this on Stack Overflow. A more descriptive title will help you get better answers, make your title as specific to the actual problem as possible. And while you're at it, there are a few issues with your code formatting, I tried to fix them but couldn't submit the edit because of "problem" in the title. Please fix those issues as well. Thanks.

Comment: Override equals and hashcode method appropriatly as per your unique column combination

Answer (score 1):

Why are you defining two `id` columns(both `id` and `source` are mapped with annotation `@Id`)?

```
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="SOURCE")
    public Integer getSource() {
        return source;
    }
```

Please remove one if it is by mistake. If both together make `composite key`, map them accordingly e.g.

```
  @Embeddable
  public class UserPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "SOURCE", nullable = false)
    private Integer source;

    .....
    .....
   }


Use this new class in you original class as Id as below:

   @EmbeddedId
   private UserPK userPK;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i added the second column because the uniqueness is on id and source. I was originally using just id and i get the same result. The second ID annotation doesn't seem to matter. I did see examples of composite keys like you placed here. I will add that. As i am new to hibernate, do you think this will fix my problem?

Comment: One way or the other. If `source` is the primary key, remove `@Id` annotation from  `getId()`. If two fields together are composite key, use the composite key mapping.

Comment: I created the composite key(Embeddable and EmbeddedId) and that fixed my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to know, it worked. If so, please accept the answer to close this thread.